# How to put a LaTeX project (template) under a license

Tags: licensing

This is mostly off topic, but related to LaTeX.

I have a template which contains about 40 files in different folders. And additionally some packages (`.sty` files) which shall be published soon.

The packages contain the typical copyright statement and *LaTeX Project Public License* lines.
Are these also necessary in the `.tex` files which contain the docs or can I create a `licence.txt` file for the whole folder?

For the template I also wonder if I can put everything under a license with a single file. Putting 10-30 lines of license statement in each file is something I want to avoid.

Comment: Having a dedicated license file is a good idea. You could then add a reference to it inside every file, which reduces the copyright header to about two lines.

Answer (score 6):

At least a few years back i was told that the CTAN team does **not** want a dedicated license file, because of "old" licenses if the package is not updated anymore.

The [LaTeX Project](http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/) has a site "How to use the LPPL". Maybe that's a good start and that's what i use. ;-)

```
  %% pig.dtx
  %% Copyright 2005 M. Y. Name
  %
  % This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
  % conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
  % of this license or (at your option) any later version.
  % The latest version of this license is in
  %   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
  % and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
  % version 2005/12/01 or later.
  %
  % This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
  % 
  % The Current Maintainer of this work is M. Y. Name.
  %
  % This work consists of the files pig.dtx and pig.ins
  % and the derived file pig.sty.
```

Comment: That works for a sty file. In those files I have it like that. But for a complete project (with only .tex files) this does not make sense. For my template I do not think that lppl is the best licence anyway. It could as well be GPL or a BSD like licence.

Answer (score 3):

I'd put the license lines in every file which contains something more than trivial code. Hey, it is just copy and paste and you prevent that

1. the legal situation of a file is unclear, and please consider what Debian people do with such files, and
2. anybody else claims you code as his own.

If none of your files is non-trivial, but you assume that the collection is the value, than the license.txt might do it.