# is the lppl license suitable also for templates or use lgpl

Tags: licensing

I have almost no knowledge about licences and there differences. I use the standard LaTeX licence (lppl) for my sty files. Now I wonder if this licence is also suitable for a template. Previously I had not put any licence to my template and that resulting in two annoying things:

1. it was changed and put online under a different name. This happened to a very early version and I found this code in a forum, where I could only give the advise to use my updated version instead.
2. I got asked several times if I allow people to publish the pdf when my template was used. (Sure)

If lppl would have too many restrictions, would lgpl be suitable? If so, how would I put the project under that licence. I can not put every file under a licence. I could add a single file called licence.txt. But what would that contain? The text from [gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html)?

Note that I had asked this more or less before
[how-to-put-a-latex-project-template-under-a-license](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56261/how-to-put-a-latex-project-template-under-a-license), but with no useful answer.

Comment: The LPPL doesn't pose any restriction about *using* the “Work” for producing a document. A document using a class/package/template released under the LPPL is not a “Derived Work”.

Comment: You might be intereset in [Frank's answer to “Is a PDF output from a LaTeX document, a “derivate work” from the LPPL standard packages?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82719/5049)

Comment: See [The GPL and LaTeX packages](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69007)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a legal problem, rather than TeX related